# SSH access to my AWS EC2 container

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

```
C:\Users\javac>ssh -i "DemoServer.pem" ubuntu@ec2-52-15-253-230.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com
The authenticity of host 'ec2-52-15-253-230.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com (52.15.253.230)' can't be established.
ED25519 key fingerprint is SHA256:1tnx8yPhul2O6mLjYH3lps7EDWaQt+UpgVGso8JsdGg.
This host key is known by the following other names/addresses:
    C:\Users\javac/.ssh/known_hosts:1: ec2-18-217-154-12.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com
    C:\Users\javac/.ssh/known_hosts:2: ec2-13-58-233-206.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'ec2-52-15-253-230.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.
ubuntu@ec2-52-15-253-230.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

I get the same thing if I try from Ubuntu run in vbox.

I did check and proper ports should be open. sshd is running on the server.

The pem file I'm using is not the first one I generated. It's 3rd or 4th one.

I've check the windows and linux permissions and tried to set them so they were not public for the pem file.

Before I got this message I got a message saying the pem file was too open.

Comment: Usually you don't access a container over ssh. But use the container management tools to manage the container.

Comment: Are you talking about AWS CLI?

Answer (score 0):

OK, well it seems after you create the initial ec2 and make a pem file you can't just make a new one without some steps in the ec2 to fix it on the server side.

Stop the running EC2 instance.

Detach its /dev/xvda1 volume (let’s call it volume A).

Start a new t1.micro EC2 instance, using your new key pair. Make sure you create it in the same subnet, otherwise you will have to terminate the instance and create it again.

Attach volume A to the new micro instance, as /dev/xvdf (or /dev/sdf).
SSH to the new micro instance and mount volume A to /mnt/tmp.
Copy ~/.ssh/authorized_keys to /mnt/tmp/home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys.
Logout.
Terminate the micro instance.
Detach volume A from it.
Attach volume A back to the main instance as /dev/xvda.
Start the main instance.
Login as before, using your new .pem file.

So what I did was create a new instance and then just log in with ssh, worked fine. For Putty I may need to convert the pem to the putty ppk file, not generate a new ppk.